# subset variable names in R using more than one condition

Tags: r, loops, tidyverse

I have the following code:

```
df <- data.frame(
  check.names = FALSE,
  `Att-Bissen P [mm]` = c(57937.8),
  `Att-Bissen PET [mm]` = c(39472.9),
  `Att-Bissen Q [mm]` = c(26501.2),
  `Rau. Merl P [mm]` = c(53443.6),
  `Rau. Merl PET [mm]` = c(40535.45),
  `Rau. Merl Q [mm]` = c(15489.5),
  `Syre Felsmuhle/Mertert P [mm]` = c(46020.3),
  `Syre Felsmuhle/Mertert PET [mm]` = c(42196.4),
  `Syre Felsmuhle/Mertert Q [mm]` = c(16210.69079),
  `Wiltz-Winseler P [mm]` = c(63389.7),
  `Wiltz-Winseler PET [mm]` = c(42703.3),
  `Wiltz-Winseler Q [mm]` = c(33576.8),
  `Our-Gemund/Vianden P [mm]` = c(63389.7),
  `Our-Gemund/Vianden PET [mm]` = c(42834.5),
  `Our-Gemund/Vianden Q [mm]` = c(12588.9))

# Define the formula as a function
calc_formula <- function(P, PET, Q, n) {
  1 - (1 + (P / PET)^n) ^ -((n + 1) / (n + Q))
}

# Define the n value
n <- 2.5

# Extract the site names from the column names
site_names <- sub(" .*", "", names(df)[-1])

# Loop through each site and calculate the formula
results <- list()
for (site in site_names) {
  site_data <- df[, grepl(site, names(df))]
  results[[site]] <- calc_formula(site_data[[paste0(site, " P [mm]")]], 
                                  site_data[[paste0(site, " PET [mm]")]], 
                                  site_data[[paste0(site, " Q [mm]")]], n)
}

# Combine the results into a data frame
results_df <- data.frame(Site = names(results), Result = unlist(results))
```

and the following error:

```
Error in data.frame(Site = names(results), Result = unlist(results)) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 5, 3
```

I think it happens because I am not able to specify in "site_names" that it should also consider the "." and the " " (space). But I am not able to determine how R can identify that the space for example, is taken at some names but not before P, PET or Q. Therefore, it returns NA in the sites of "Rau. Merl" and "Syre Felsmuhle/Mertert".

I can easily change the names in the .csv file but when I have a robust data set is quite tedious.

How can I fix that part of the code?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!!

Comment: Have you considered to change the data format? Column names to a row. `P`, `PET`, `Q` in seperate columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got two problems. First, let's look at your site names:

```
site_names
#  [1] "Att-Bissen"         "Att-Bissen"         "Rau."               "Rau."              
#  [5] "Rau."               "Syre"               "Syre"               "Syre"              
#  [9] "Wiltz-Winseler"     "Wiltz-Winseler"     "Wiltz-Winseler"     "Our-Gemund/Vianden"
# [13] "Our-Gemund/Vianden" "Our-Gemund/Vianden"
# Loop through each site and calculate the formula
```

Two problems here: 1) the repetition is bad as you only want one result per site. We can put a `... |> unique()` at the end to remove the duplicates. 2) You've extracted the site names by removing everything after the first space. As you say, some of your site names have spaces in them, like `"Rau. Merl"`.

Let's fix this by removing the specific parts of the string you actually want to remove. We'll do this using the regex or: `|` and suitable escapes for the brackets.

```
site_names <- sub(" P \\[mm\\]| PET \\[mm\\]| Q \\[mm\\]", "", names(df)[-1]) |>
  unique()
site_names
# [1] "Att-Bissen"             "Rau. Merl"              "Syre Felsmuhle/Mertert" "Wiltz-Winseler"        
# [5] "Our-Gemund/Vianden"
```

Running the rest of your code, it now works:

```
# ...
results_df
#                                          Site       Result
# Att-Bissen                         Att-Bissen 0.0001695120
# Rau. Merl                           Rau. Merl 0.0002478667
# Syre Felsmuhle/Mertert Syre Felsmuhle/Mertert 0.0001742918
# Wiltz-Winseler                 Wiltz-Winseler 0.0001359271
# Our-Gemund/Vianden         Our-Gemund/Vianden 0.0003609042
```

Answer (score 2):

My feeling is that it might be advantageous to have the data in long format.

Notice that, `reshape()` or functions from `{tidyr}` like `pivot_longer()` are certainly capable of doing this in a more robust way.

**Reshape**

```
new = data.frame(
  unique(sub(" P \\[mm\\]| PET \\[mm\\]| Q \\[mm\\]", "", names(df))), 
  matrix(as.numeric(df[1L, ]), ncol = 3L, byrow = TRUE)) |> 
  setNames(object = _, nm = c("stations", "P", "PET", "Q"))
```

The `sub()`-approach is stolen from @GregorThomas's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77621918/20002111). We then apply a modified version of `calc_formula()` row-wisely.

**Apply**

```r
# slightly modified
calc_formula <- function(row, n = 2.5) {
  1L - (1L + (row[["P"]] / row[["PET"]])^n) ^ -((n + 1L) / (n + row[["Q"]]))
}
new$result = apply(X = new[-1L], MARGIN = 1L, FUN = calc_formula)
```

**Result**

```r
> new
                stations       P      PET        Q       result
1             Att-Bissen 57937.8 39472.90 26501.20 0.0001695120
2              Rau. Merl 53443.6 40535.45 15489.50 0.0002478667
3 Syre Felsmuhle/Mertert 46020.3 42196.40 16210.69 0.0001742918
4         Wiltz-Winseler 63389.7 42703.30 33576.80 0.0001359271
5     Our-Gemund/Vianden 63389.7 42834.50 12588.90 0.0003609042
```

---

**Data**

```r
df <- data.frame(
  check.names = FALSE,
  `Att-Bissen P [mm]` = c(57937.8),
  `Att-Bissen PET [mm]` = c(39472.9),
  `Att-Bissen Q [mm]` = c(26501.2),
  `Rau. Merl P [mm]` = c(53443.6),
  `Rau. Merl PET [mm]` = c(40535.45),
  `Rau. Merl Q [mm]` = c(15489.5),
  `Syre Felsmuhle/Mertert P [mm]` = c(46020.3),
  `Syre Felsmuhle/Mertert PET [mm]` = c(42196.4),
  `Syre Felsmuhle/Mertert Q [mm]` = c(16210.69079),
  `Wiltz-Winseler P [mm]` = c(63389.7),
  `Wiltz-Winseler PET [mm]` = c(42703.3),
  `Wiltz-Winseler Q [mm]` = c(33576.8),
  `Our-Gemund/Vianden P [mm]` = c(63389.7),
  `Our-Gemund/Vianden PET [mm]` = c(42834.5),
  `Our-Gemund/Vianden Q [mm]` = c(12588.9))
```

Comment: Long format is a big improvement here!